# Merging csv columns while checking ID of the first column

Tags: python, database, csv

I have a 4 csv files exported from e-shop database I need to merge them by columns, which I would maybe manage to do alone. But the problem is to match the right columns

First file:

```
"ep_ID","ep_titleCS","ep_titlePL".....

"601","Kancelářská židle šedá",NULL.....

...
```

Second file:

```
"pe_photoID","pe_productID","pe_sort"

"459","603","1"


...
```

Third file:

```
"epc_productID","epc_categoryID","epc_root"

"2155","72","1"


...
```

Fourth file:

```
"ph_ID","ph_titleCS"...

"379","5391132275.jpg"
```

...

I need to match the rows so rows with same "ep_ID" and "epc_productID" are merged together and rows with same "ph_ID", "pe_photoID" too. I don't really know where to start, hopefully, I wrote it understandably

Update: 
I am using :

```
files = ['produkty.csv', 'prirazenifotek.csv', 'pprirazenikategorii.csv', 'adresyfotek.csv']
dfs = []

for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f,low_memory=False)
    dfs.append(df)

first_and_third =pd.merge(dfs[0],dfs[1],left_on = "ep_ID",right_on="pe_photoID")

first_and_third.to_csv('new_filepath.csv', index=False)
```

Ok this code works, but it does two things in another way than I need:

1. When there is a row in file one with ID = 1 for example and in the next file two there is 5 rows with bID = 1, then it creates 5 rows int the final file I would like to have one row that would have multiple values from every row with bID = 1 in file number two. Is it possible?
2. And it seems to be deleting some rows... not sure till i get rid of the "duplicates"...

Comment: Is it possible to do while using another package or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas`'s `merge` method to merge the csvs together. In your question you only provide keys between the 1st and 3rd files, and the 2nd and 4th files. Not sure if you want one giant table that has them all together -- if so you will need to find another intermediary key, maybe one you haven't listed(?).

```
import pandas as pd

files = ['path_to_first_file.csv', 'second_file.csv', 'third_file.csv', 'fourth_file.csv']
dfs = []

for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    dfs.append(df)

first_and_third = dfs[0].merge(dfs[2], left_on='ep_ID', right_on='epc_productID', how='left')
second_and_fourth = dfs[1].merge(dfs[3], left_on='pe_photoID', right_on='ph_ID', how='left')
```

If you want to save the dataframe back down to a file you can do so:

```
first_and_third.to_csv('new_filepath.csv', index=False)
```

`index=False` assumes you have no index set on the dataframe and don't want the dataframe's row numbers to be included in the final csv.

Comment: Thank you, seems good but I am getting weird error:
   
 df = pd.read_csv(files[f])


TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @Jakub Apologies -- typo. Replace `pd.read_csv(files[f])` with `pd.read_csv(f)`

Comment: ok now I am getting :  ValueError: len(left_on) must equal the number of levels in the index of "right"
Read I should use merge instead? Trying to do it now

Comment: I tried : first_and_third =pd.merge(dfs[0],dfs[2], on=['ep_ID', 'epc_productID']) and got error: KeyError: 'ep_ID'

Comment: @Jakub `dfs[0].merge(dfs[2], left_on='ep_ID', right_on='epc_productID')`